# Get a file name with tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename to append in it

Tags: python, tkinter, filedialog

from an GUI application designed with `tkinter`, I wish to save some datas in a file in appending mode. To get the file's name I use `asksaveasfilename` from `filedialog` module. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

def save_file():

    file_name = asksaveasfilename()

    if file_name:
        f = open(file_name, 'a')
        contents = tab_chrono.text_area.get(1.0, 'end')
        f.write(contents)
        f.close()
```

The problem happens when I select in the dialog an existing file, I got a warning that the file will be overwritten. It is not true since I append in the file. 
Is there a way to get rid of this warning ? Or do I have to rewrite a `askappendfilename` myself ? This is missing in `filedialog` module.
[image]

Comment: if you always select file to append (but you newer create new one) then you could use `askopenfilename` but it will display button "Open" instead of 'Save` (you can set window title="Open to append") . Or you will have to create own dialog.

Comment: Unfortunately I want to create a new file if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: So you will have to create own Dialog. Try `print(tkinter.filedialog.__file__)` to see path to file with `asksaveasfilename` (and other file dialogs). You may use this code to create own version. Or create from scratch :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `asksaveasfilename` dialog accepts a `confirmoverwrite` argument to enable or disable the file existence check.

```
file_name = asksaveasfilename(confirmoverwrite=False)
```

This can be found in the Tk manual for [tk_getSaveFile](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/getOpenFile.htm) but doesn't appear to be documented for tkinter. It was introduced in Tk 8.5.11 so is relatively new in Tk terms (released Nov 2011).

Comment: Also documented at the following links, yet none of them are Tkinter. https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/getOpenFile.htm http://tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/382.html http://www.manpagez.com/man/n/tk_getSaveFile/

Answer (score 3):

Use the option `confirmoverwrite` to prevent the message, when selecting an existing file.

```
import tkFileDialog 
import time
class Example():

    dlg = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(confirmoverwrite=False)
    fname = dlg
    if fname != '':
        try:
            f = open(fname, "rw+")
            text = f.read()
            print text
        except:
            f = open(fname, "w")
        new_text = time.time()
        f.write(str(new_text)+'\n')
        f.close()
```

Edit: Note that I am using `f.read()` to be able to print the existing text.
You may want to remove the `f.read()` and subsequent `print` statement and replace them with a `f.seek(0,2)` which positions the pointer at the end of the existing file.
The other option is as follows using the `append` option in the file open, which will create the file if it doesn't already exist:

```
import tkFileDialog 
import time
class Example():

    dlg = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(confirmoverwrite=False)
    fname = dlg
    if fname != '':
        f = open(fname, "a")
        new_text = time.time()
        f.write(str(new_text)+'\n')
        f.close()
```

Comment: If the file doesn't exists, askopenfile generates an error message. If the file doesn't exist I want to create it. If it exists, I want to append into it

Comment: You didn't stipulate that in your question. See my edited answer.